# how to create variable of type Bitmap to an Object

Tags: actionscript-3

Is it possible to make an Object that contains a variable of type Bitmap.

what i mean is that i create a Bitmap with bitmapData like this

```
var  swordBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new Sword_0());
```

but how do i pass that data into a variable of an Object

Im trying to obtain the Bitmap directly into the Object like this.

```
public static const SWORD1:Object = { Image:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new Sword_0());, DMG:10, Cost: 50 }
```

and then somehow to use it like this

```
var myWeapon:Sprite = new Sprite;
myWeapon.addChild(SWORD1.Image)
```

or what im doing is not quite right / is not possible.

PS: **Sword_0** is the name of the image in the library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Select your bitmap in the library and make sure you select "Export for ActionScript" in the "Actionscript" tab.  Give the bitmap a class name and your code will look something like this...

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Bitmap;

var struct:Object = {
    "bitmap":new Bitmap(new myImg())
}


var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
mySprite.addChild(struct.bitmap);
addChild(mySprite);
```

Comment: 10x for the fast response and easy to get answer :D